# How to perform linear regression when each data item is itself a distribution?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have two sets of data $R$ and $R^{'}$, and I would like to perform regression to infer whether for some function $f$ (which I postulate) and some data item $E$ (representing noise), there exists a relationship $R' = f(R,E)$.

Initially I thought I would try some linear function such as $f(R,E) = \alpha R + \beta E = R^{'}$ - clearly a task for linear regression. However, my problem is that each data item in both $R$ and $R^{'}$ is itself a distribution rather than just single values for $R$ and $R^{'}$, i.e. a tuple of values - specifically these are quantum mechanical measurements of qubit states, where we are performing measurements on a given state vector and count the measurement outcomes, which are either 1s or 0s for a given qubit. For example, when measuring a 2 qubit state we can get (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), or (1,1), and we would thus then have a tuple with 4 elements in, where the values represent either the raw number of counts of each state, or estimates of the probabilities when normalised by the total number of samples.

I was wondering therefore whether it's still possible to carry out regression in this case? Or does this require some feature engineering beforehand in order to convert these distributions into metrics which are single valued?

Comment: A tuple does not automatically imply a distribution, so you are likely making some undisclosed assumption by treating it as one. Can each tuple perhaps be considered a sample from a corresponding random variable?

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy, thanks for answering. 

Yes, I am indeed making some undisclosed assumptions, apologies. Each tuple is actually a discrete probability distribution, where each element represents a probability for a specific outcome. Accordingly element one for a given set of tuples in both $R$ and $R^{'}$ represent the corresponding probabilities for that particular outcome within those datasets etc. So yes, the tuples can essentially be considered as the number of counts when sampling from a (discrete) random variable.

Comment: How do you obtain these probabilities?  If they are counts or proportions, then they are not probabilities.  The distinction is important.

Comment: You need to give more details&context, maybe an example of what the data looks like..  But loke into functional regression! Search this site.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the question. Okay, so these are really counts/proportions, so we sample from some unknown distribution, we get the number of each outcome, but then normalise by the total number of samples - these then represent estimates of the probabilities, right?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the comment, these are quantum mechanical measurements of qubit states - we are performing measurements on a given state vector, and count the measurement outcomes, which are either 1s or 0s for a given qubit, so for example when measuring a 2 qubit state we can get (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), or (1,1). We would thus then have a tuple with 4 elements in, where the values represent either the number of counts of each state, or estimates of the probabilities when normalised by the total number of samples. Is 'functional regression' still appropriate?

Comment: The crux of the matter is whether the uncertainties in the probability estimates are large enough to matter.  What are typical sizes of the counts you are getting?

Comment: @whuber I'd have to get back to you tomorrow on that with some orders of magnitude, but for argument sake, what are my options in either case (i.e. counts are quite low so uncertainties are important or are large enough that they can be ignored)?

Comment: With large counts you are in an ordinary multivariate (that is, vector response) regression setting and with small counts you are in a potentially complicated errors-in-variables setting (where the errors in the explanatory variables may vary with their values: that is, they are heteroscedastic).  In either case it's important to know, assume, or estimate the covariance matrix of $R^\prime.$

Comment: @whuber, I've checked, on average the number of samples (total number of counts) is ~7500, the average number of counts per outcome is ~20, so the average estimated probabilities are ~20/7500. Which regime would you say this is?

Comment: The variance of a count is the count itself; thus, counts around $20$ have sampling errors of $\sqrt{20}\approx 4.5.$ That is an appreciable proportion of $20.$ I would say you need to be concerned about these sampling errors and should at least explore the merits of errors-in-variables regression methods.  You should also be using a multivariate Poisson generalized linear model (GLM) for the response if you can.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the info! Do you have any links to good references/resources to read regarding error-in-variables regression and multivariate Poisson generalised linear models?

Comment: We have had a lot of posts about GLMs here on several on different forms of errors-in-variables regression, so consider a site search.

Comment: @whuber It turns out a colleague gave me some incorrect information and the actual average number of counts is 375, so then we would have sampilng errors of ~5%. Does this influence our regime regarding the type of regression?

Comment: It depends.  The relevant quantity to consider is the ratio of the variance of an individual count to the variance of the set of values of the explanatory variables: when this ratio becomes sizeable (maybe around 10% or so, depending on the application) you ought to consider its effects on the regression.

Comment: @whuber Great, thank you! Just to confirm then, the relevant things to consider are these ratios for the distributions of $R$ and $E$ in the above discussion i.e. the explanatory variables. The uncertainties on the counts of $R'$ (the response variable) are not of importance?

Comment: The uncertainties in the response are important, but they are part of any standard regression model.  "Errors in variables" models also account for any substantial uncertainties in the explanatory variables.